# is there a way to create a FB app for a single page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I want to create a FB app for a client's Facebook Page.  How do I do this without allowing other pages accessing it as well?  Obviously I can do an ID check in my code, but I presume there's a 'proper' way of denying access to all and sundry?

Comment: do you want to restrict access of the app so that only the owner sees it or a select group of users?

Comment: no - I want to restrict it's install base - any users who land on the facebook page should be able to see it

Comment: I guess I could just hard code the facebook page id that it's applicable to on my end and don't show any permissioning granting screens to anyone who happens to type in the app url manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to make an application private as in you're the only person that can install it but you could look into using the [Static FBML box](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?sid=4f93513c73973214f42f630bfb78603c&id=4949752878&ref=s), you can have FBJS, FBML, CSS and HTML incorporated into that box and you'll be the only one able to use it.

Comment: I think that's your best bet if you don't want to be forced to use the Static FBML box